# make a https OPTIONS request which returns a JSON body

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, https

How can i make a https OPTIONS request to an existing REST endpoint using node.js?

When I use postman with the OPTIONS request method i get back the JSON body of all the existing endpoints.

I followed the node.js docs and here is what i am doing -

```
var options = {
    hostname: host,
    port: 443,
    path: urlPar,
    method: 'OPTIONS'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res){
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

    res.on('data', function(d) {
        console.log("returned data", d);
    });
});

req.end();

req.on('error', function(e){
    console.error("error thrown", e);
});
```

But i get this error for the request -

```
{ [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }
```

Is there another way how to do this?

Comment: Sounds that your `host` can not be resolved. Your DNS cannot get the ip address. Check the value of `host`

Comment: value of the host and the urlPar is correct as i use the same URL in postman. But is this the way to make an OPTIONS request?

Comment: Make sur that host does not have `https://` it should be only the FQDN.

Comment: aah. too quick to post it here. was including the https://. Thank you.

Comment: `getaddrinfo` is the one that tell you what is going wrong. A quick man on `getaddrinfo` and you would have seen that there is something wrong when resolving your host name to an IP address. :) You can answer your question and accept your own answer.